# Iterating over numbers with leading zeroes with a `for` loop

Tags: php

I'm working on a calendar site and need to change the following code to show `0` before the value of `$list_day` if it's a single digit number.

```
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Leading "0"s mean nothing to a *number*: they are simply an artifact of a given *text representation* (it can mean octal or just be padding, as in the post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($list_day < 10)
  echo "0" . $list_day;
else
  echo $list_day;
```

Comment: use string concatenation '.' instead adding '+'

Comment: @RiaD Thanks for taking care of that

Comment: @Juhana Maaaaaaan ... I've been writing in VB6 for 3 days and I'm already missing ; :(

Comment: Thanks I can mode this for what I need. Seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 7):

When you're printing it, use `sprintf("%02d", $list_day)` to pad it with a zero.

Comment: Don't need to print the value but this is great to know for later!

Comment: Oh ok... this doesn't actually print it though! Whatever you need it for, running it through `sprintf(...)` appends the `0`.

Comment: @Philip - If you're not printing it somewhere, the leading zero makes no difference

Comment: @bemace he could conceivably be passing it to some other function that expects a zero-padded string.

Comment: @PhilipK sprintf don't prints, it returns string

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%02d",$listday);


printf("%02d",3);  //prints 03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo sprintf('%02d',$list_day);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as

```
for ($list_day = "01"; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day = sprintf("%02d", $list_day + 1))
```

but it's usually done like

```
for ($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++) {
    print "<div>" . sprintf("%02d", $list_day) . "...</div>";
}
```

Comment: In the first method you'd be incrementing a string after the first loop. PHP might just interpret `"02"` as the integer `2` but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @Juhana - String concatenation is done with `.` in PHP; when using `+` it autoconverts strings to integers correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought :) You should start with $list_day = "01" then, though.

Comment: Instead of calling `sprintf()` inside of `print`, just call `printf()` and write all of the literal strings inside the first parameter of `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($list_day < 10)
    $new_day = '0'.$list_day;
else
    $new_day = $list_day;
```

Comment: This will probably mess up the loop. It's better not to touch the original variable.